# why docker virtualization is faster vs VM

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

From what I understand, VMs use hardware virtualization, whereas dockers use software virtualization and therefore have better performance (in a case, lets say, I am running a Dockerized Linux on a Windows machine). But what is exactly the reason that OS virtualization is faster than hardware virtualization?

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048358/4980651 and many other answers under this question, they give you a good overview of the underlying docker technologies which gives it an edge on performance

Answer (score 11):

Docker doesn't do virtualization.  It uses [kernel namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces) to achieve a chroot-like effect not just for the root filesystem but process information (PID namespace), mount points, networking, IPC (shared memory), UTS information (hostname) & user id's.

The containers share the kernel with the host.  For security Docker uses AppArmor/SELinux, [Linux capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and [seccomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) to filter system calls.  Control groups (known as [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)] are used for process accounting and for imposing limits on resources.

Comment: You say that the containers share the kernel with the host, but how can they share a kernel if the docker image contains a different OS than the host? (e.g Dockerized Linux on a Windows host)

Comment: @Mister_L If you run a CentOS container on a Debian system, it is running the CentOS binaries (and libraries) but not the CentOS provided kernel.  Any container on a Debian system will use the kernel installed on that system.

Answer (score 7):

Docker is not about *virtualization*. It's about *containerization* (how to run a process in an isolated environment).

This means that **you can't run a linux container on windows** or **a windows container on linux** without using some kind of virtualization (Virtualbox, Hyper-v...) It's ok to do this on your laptop while developing but in production you would choose the appropriate architecture for your containers.

## What is a container?

from [A sysadmin's guide to containers](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/sysadmins-guide-containers):

> Traditional Linux containers are really just **ordinary processes** on a Linux system. These groups of processes are **isolated** from other groups of processes using resource constraints:
>
> - (control groups [**cgroups**]),
> - Linux security constraints (Unix permissions, capabilities, SELinux, AppArmor, seccomp, etc.), and
> - **namespaces** (PID, network, mount, etc.).

Setting all these manually (network namespaces, iptable-rules etc..) with linux commands would be tricky, so it's the docker-daemon's job to do them when you type `docker ...` commands and things happen under the hood...

## About speed...

First of all, containers can be less fast than running a process directly on the host networking stack, because of the complexity which is introduced. See for example this: [Performance issues running nginx in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023800/performance-issues-running-nginx-in-a-docker-container)

But, they will offer you **speed**. How?:

- containers are not full OSs (**base images have small size**)
- containers follow the concepts of micro-services and "do one thing, do it well". This means that you don't put everything in a container the same way you would do with VMs. This is called **separation of concerns** and it results in more lightweight app components. It also gives speed to developers because different teams can work on their component separately (others also mention this as **developer velocity**) with different programming languages and frameworks.
- **image layers**: docker has an internal way of splitting an image to layers and when you build a new image, layers **can be reused**. This gives you good deployment speeds (consider how useful this is in case of a rollback)

## About Windows Containers

Containers was a "linux" thing but this wave of containerization has also had an effect on the Windows land. In the beginning `docker-toolbox` was using Virtualbox to run containers on a linux VM. Later, `docker-for-windows` was introduced and gives the option to run containers directly on the host or on `hyper-v`. If  you visit [Windows Container Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/#windows-container-types) you can find more.